# Как правильно использовать Connection Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, база-данных, mariadb

Всем привет.
Хочу начать использовать `connection pool` в асинхронном приложении, но не понимаю как правильно с ним работать...

Буду писать на основе [mysql.connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html)

Это просто пример подключения

```
from mysql.connector import pooling

def main():
    pool = pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(
        pool_name="MariaDB",
        autocommit=True,
        pool_size=32,
        **db_config
    )
    conn = pool.get_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Подключаюсь без ошибок

**Вопросы:**

1. Если запустить программу снова, закроется ли весь пул?
2. Время жизни соединения ограничено. Удалится ли соединение, время жизни которого истекло и создастся ли новый?
3. Стоит ли каждый раз, после запроса, закрывать соединение/курсор?

Comment: 1. нет. пул живет в запущеном процессе, пока существуют на него ссылки. При выходе из программы, пул уничтожается и все соединения к БД, которыми владеет пул, закрываются. Между пулами созданными в разных программах нет никакой прямой связи (кроме той, что они конкурируют за ограниченное в самой БД количество одновременно открытых соединений)  2. о каком ограничении на время жизни речь? 3. обязательно нужно закрывать. При закрытии соединения, оно возвращается в пул

Comment: Помните, что работа через пул отличается от работы в соединении. В частности, придётся забыть о пользовательских переменных, временных таблицах, настройке режима сессии и пр.

Comment: @Akina с переменными сессии проблем быть не должно. В mysql.connector за это отвечает параметр конфигурации pool_reset_session, нужно его поставить в True и переменные очистятся, когда соединение из пула возвращается клиенту.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Вообще-то я об обратном. Вот нужно моему запросу, чтобы он выполнялся при особых настройках (скажем, отключить `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` в `@@sql_mode` или увеличить `@@group_concat_max_len`). Если изменение будет выполнено в одном соединении, а потом запрос в другом - пичалька, а не ожидаемый результат. Надо выполнять запрос на изменение параметров и целевой запрос одним батчем, в одном вызове `.execute`. И начинается - а не забудь батчем, а разреши мультизапрос, а разберись с коллекцией выходных наборов...

Comment: @Akina Это как раз не проблема, в этой реализации пул на уровне соединений, а не statement-ов (как иногда бывает). Т.е. pool.get_connection возвращает обертку над реальным соединением. И дальше вся работа с ним, т.е. все запросы будут выполены в одном реальном соединении, так что проблем описаных выше не будет.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Эммм... я правильно понял, что пул - это не распараллеливание (последовательные асинхронные запросы выполняются в разных connection), а наоборот - агрегирование с целью снижения общего числа соединений от экземпляра приложения?

Comment: @Akina да, правильно, если пулятся соединения. Цели две 1. уменьшить время открытия соединения (берем готовое) 2. ограничить общее число соединений (если уже окрыли много, то ждем пока не освободится). Бывает еще пул операторов, тогда каждая операция выполянется отдельно и может быть выполенена в отдельном соединении (про асинхронные правда не слышал) Но обычно это не используют, так как тут транзакции невозможны и плюс проблемы с сессиями, что вы описали.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Ну тогда только потенция косяка, если два потока команд начнут строить сессию каждый под себя, разделяя одно соединение. Или это тоже исключено - пул пулом, но коли зацепил из него соединение, то оно теперь эксклюзивно твоё - до закрытия?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136753/discussion-between-roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua-and-akina).