# Как сделать единое подключение к бд (использую aiomysql)

Tags: python, aiogram, pymysql

Стал использовать библиотеку aiomysql для асинхронного подключения к бд.
Раньше использовал mysql.connector и подключался к бд только один раз.
В документации aiomysql нет ни одного примера для подключения к бд всего один раз, там есть единый метод, в котором происходят и подключение и запросы. В своей программе я много работаю с бд и на взятие каких-либо данных из бд у меня несколько методов, не буду же я в каждом методе заново подключаться к базе данных.
Как мне сделать подключение к бд одиножды и использовать его в других методах?

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

conn = await connect(host=host, port=port, user=user, password=password, db=db, 
                     charset='utf8', use_unicode=True, loop=loop)

async def add_user(user: usermodel):
    cur = await conn.cursor(prepared=True)

    try:
        await cur.execute('INSERT INTO Users (Phone, ...) VALUES (?, ...)',
                          (user.phone, ...))
    except aiomysql.Error as ex:
        print(f'Error insert: {ex}')
        sys.exit(1)

    await conn.commit()
    await cur.close()
```

Данный код демонстрирует то, что я хотел бы видеть на aiomysql

ps: формат подключения к бд в коде выше был реализован с помощью mariadb connector, такой же формат подключения использует и mysql connector, хочу такую же реализацию на aiomysql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481826/how-can-i-use-connection-pool-in-aiomysql

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin - я видел этот кусок кода, как я понял, там выполняется 2 таска асинхронно при запуске программы, но мне это не подходит. Условно у меня есть функция в файле бд, которая выполняет запрос на получение юзера по id и я должен в произвольный момент вызвать эту функцию (user = await db.getUser(id=1)). И таких функций много. Мне не нужен метод, который будет превращать все эти функции в таски вызывать все эти таски. Сейчас вставлю код того, что именно я хотел бы

Comment: Вы не разобрались с тем ответом. Не нужны таски - не создавайте (там это просто у автора вопроса такая структура кода, к сути вашей задачи не имеет отношения). Вам нужно воспользоваться  aiomysql.create_pool один раз. И потом каждый раз использовать созданный пул, чтоб из него брать соединение с помощью pool.acquire.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA - а чем вообще отличается aiomysql.connect от aiomysql.create_pool, не совсем понимаю просто

Comment: Первый создает соединение с БД, а второй создает пул соединений (вам как раз он и нужен, одним соединением не обойтись). Вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1416068/218971 было обсуждение, как работает пул

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Так, хорошо, если я правильно понял, то для асинхронной работы бд нормальная практика после проработки метода закрытие соединение и при вызове другого опять производить коннект к бд? И все же, если возвращаться к моему коду и теме выше, то как мне передать этот пул в произвольно вызванную функцию? В синхронной бд можно создать глобальную переменную с коннектом, в асинхронном соединении приходится обертывать в функцию, вследствие чего у нас уже нет возможности обратиться к этой переменной

Comment: "нормальная практика после проработки метода закрытие соединение" - нет, не так поняли. Нормальная практика использовать пул и закрывать соединение, тогда оно реально не закроется, а вернется в пул. "вследствие чего у нас уже нет возможности обратиться к этой переменной" - это не так, и почему такой вывод сделали мне непонятно. Ссылку на пул можно взять из глобальной переменной, а можно передать параметром в функцию.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Моя глобальная переменная обнуляется. То есть после компиляции, программа пробегается по основному файлу, в котором у нас глобальная переменная (conn = None) и функция с подключением к бд, когда происходит взаимодействие с файлом бд, мы импортируем нашу глобальную переменную из основного файла и она почему-то None, хотя в основном файле в нее из функции записались данные коннекта

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Если передавать в качестве параметра в функцию, то в функции коннекта придется вызывать функцию с каким-либо запросом к бд - это как раз причина, по которой я создал эту тему, мне нужны методы запросов отделить от метода коннекта

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Нашел решение, сейчас опубликую, если вас в нем что-то не устроит, то рад буду критике (желательно с пояснениями)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

settings.py:

```
class Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        self._conn = None

    @property
    def conn(self):
        return self._conn

    @conn.setter
    def conn(self, value):
        self._conn = value


settings = Settings()
```

main.py:

```
import ...
from settings import settings

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


async def main():
    if not settings.conn:
        try:
            settings.conn = await create_pool(host=HOST, port=PORT, user=USER, 
                                          password=PASSWORD,
                                          db=DATABASE, charset='utf8',
                                          use_unicode=True, loop=loop)
        except aiomysql.Error as e:
            print(f'Error connecting: {e}')
            sys.exit(1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

db.py:

```
import ...
from settings import settings


async def user_info(attr, val):
    data = None
    pool = settings.conn
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            try:
                await cur.executemany('SELECT phone, ... FROM Table' 
                                      f'WHERE {attr} = %s', (val,))
            except aiomysql.Error as ex:
                print(f'Error select: {ex}')
                sys.exit(1)

            data = await cur.fetchall()

    pool.close()
    await pool.wait_closed()
    return data
```

Comment: Тут вы решили проблему хранения и доступа к глобальному объекту. Но в конкретном случае с Connection это не будет работать. Проблема в том, что нельзя использовать один объект Connection для выполнения нескольких запросов параллельно. А именно это будет происходить в асинхронной программе. Еще раз повторюсь, вместо Connection в setting нужно хранить пул и его использовать, чтоб каждый раз когда нужно в функции типа user_info достать оттуда новое соединение предназначенное конкретно для этого вызова user_info

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA исправил, правда тут я не знаю нужно ли делать cur.close()

Comment: `cur.close` делать не нужно. `with conn.cursor() ...` - это контекстный менеджер, который закроет курсор после выхода из блока `with`. НЕ нужно делать `pool.close` и `pool.wait_closed`. Этим вы закроете пул и все соединения в нем. Пул должен жить все время работы приложения. Все же рекомендую вам почитать про пул - вы все же не понимаете, как пул работает. В остальном - все ок. Для удобства я всегда еще делаю свой контекстный менеджер для получения сразу курсора из settings, чтоб не повторять весь этот код с `pool.acquire` и `conn.cursor`.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA да, я правда не до конца понимаю как он работает, но представление уже есть, код исправил. Спасибо вам большое